# Finding errors in known patterns from data in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to use R to determine errors in a dataset. The dataset consists of time in seconds in one column and whether a "Run" has occurred in another column. A "0" in the RunStart column indicates the beginning of a run, while a"1" is just the continuation of a run.

In the example table below, the intervals in time in a run should be **10 seconds**.

I want to find out when a run begins if all subsequent values are multiples of 10 seconds and determine all rows where this is not true. In the example, all rows are correct except row 9 which has a 9 second difference from row 8 in the same run. How can I isolate errors such as row 9 in a large dataset?

```
   Time RunStart
1   10        0
2   20        1
3   30        1
4  101        0
5  111        1
6  121        1
7  202        0
8  212        1
9  221        1
```

I am having trouble finding where to begin, I am currently looking into the "plyr" package and the introduction to data cleaning in R document on R's website. The full dataset, I am trying to find the errors in, is over 300 000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can do:

```
library(dplyr)


df %>% 
  mutate(regular = RunStart == 0 | Time - lag(Time) == 10)
#>   Time RunStart regular
#> 1   10        0    TRUE
#> 2   20        1    TRUE
#> 3   30        1    TRUE
#> 4  101        0    TRUE
#> 5  111        1    TRUE
#> 6  121        1    TRUE
#> 7  202        0    TRUE
#> 8  212        1    TRUE
#> 9  221        1   FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` to get the time differences, check which are not multiples of ten and match that against continuation records.

```
intersect(which((c(0,diff(df$Time)) %% 10) != 0), 
      which(df$RunStart == 1))
[1] 9
```